# Recommended SharePoint Online Modern Canvas Quick Link Image size

Tags: sharepoint-online

Here is a snip.

[image]

Does anyone know the recommended image size for the quick links so it looks good?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best image size should be 379px x 213px. This you can get it from the default link comes with Quick Links web part.

Create your images to render perfect for different aspect ratios.

The natural size is in the below image is recommended.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The OOTB picture size for Client Side Quick Link Web Part is `379px x 213px` while the rendering canvas/surface size is `377px x 209px`. See below:

[image: Quick Link image size]

**Note:** since the modern web part use Office Fabric for UI, which is responsive in nature, the above mentioned resolutions are majored on a full HD monitor. It may vary based on screen size. But I, guess if you maintain the aspect ratio, you image will display in proper manner.